# $N \sim Pois(\lambda), \lambda>0, X \sim Bin(N,p), p\in (0,1)$ $P(N=n,X=k) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!} {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Tags: probability

$N \sim Pois(\lambda), \lambda>0, X|N \sim Bin(N,p), p\in (0,1)$

$P(N=n,X=k) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!} {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

$(a)$ Prove X$\sim$ Pois

$(b)$ Calculate $E(X(N-X)) $ for $\lambda=3, p=0.5$

$(c)$ Prove $X-N,X$ are independent

**My solution:**

(a) $$P_X(x=k)=\sum_{i=0}^n P(N=i,X=k)=\sum_{i=0}^n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!} {i \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{i-k}$$

since $$\sum_{i=0}^n {i \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{i-k}=1$$

We get  $$P_X(x=k)=\sum_{i=0}^n P(N=i,X=k) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}\cdot 1= P_X = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!} \implies X \sim Pois(\lambda)$$

My solution for (a) is correct?

$(b)$  $E(X(N-X))=E[XN-X^2]=E[XN]-E[X^2]$.

Then $E[X^2]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty P_X(x=i)\cdot i^2$

How I get $E[XN]$ ?

I get stuck in (b),(c) and I will be grateful for the help.

Thanks !

Comment: (a) How did you pull out $\lambda^i/i!$ from the sum when it depends on the index of summation? And keep in mind the support of $N$ is infinite (0,1,2,...) (b) If you know the joint distribution, you should be able to compute the expected value of any function $g(X,N)$...use the definition, (c)Why don't you start with the definition of independence

Comment: Also if $X|N\sim Bin(N,p),$ think where your sum should start in (a). Is it possible that $i<k$? And also think, intuitively, does it make sense that the marginal distribution of $X$ would be the same as that of $N$ and have no dependency on $p$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1417669/321264

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I have a misunderstanding ," Also if $X|N∼Bin(N,p)$, think where your sum should start in (a). Is it possible that$i<k$?" $X|N\sim Bin(N,p)$, $X \sim Bin(N,p)$ is the same meaning ?

Comment: @erez oh looks like you clarified the notation in another post, so I'll delete my last remark: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359868/the-difference-x-sim-binn-p-xn-n-sim-binn-p