# The difference $X \sim Bin(N,p) , X|(N=n) \sim Bin(N,p)$

Tags: probability

I am a little confused about conditional probability and will be grateful for an explanation.

I post this [$N \sim Pois(\lambda), \lambda>0, X \sim Bin(N,p), p\in (0,1)$ $P(N=n,X=k) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!} {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359700/n-sim-pois-lambda-lambda0-x-sim-binn-p-p-in-0-1-pn-n-x-k-e?noredirect=1#comment9103688_4359700)

I have to prove that $X \sim Pois$.

One of the comments was this post with a same question [Let $N$~Pois$(\lambda)$, $X|(N=n)$~Bin$(N,p)$, $Y=N-X$. Show $X$, $Y$ are independent and Poisson with parameters $\lambda p$ and $\lambda (1-p)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417669/let-npois-lambda-xn-nbinn-p-y-n-x-show-x-y-are-indepe)

In **my** post  $X \sim Bin(N,p)$ and $P(N=n,X=k)$ is a common probability function of $(N,X)$ while in the second post $X|(N=n) \sim Bin(N,p)$

I know that $P_{X|N}(x|n)=\frac{P_{X,N}(x,n)}{P_N(n)}$

For finding $P_X$ It will be $P_X=\frac{P(N=n,X=k)}{\sum_{i=k}^\infty P_N}$? On the second post it is $P_X=P_{X|N}\cdot P_N$

Does $X \sim Bin(N,p) , X|(N=n) \sim Bin(N,p)
$ have the same meaning ?

I am really confused and will be grateful for an explanation!

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three expressions $X\sim Bin(N,p)$, $X|N\sim Bin(N,p)$ and $X|(N=n) \sim Bin(n,p)$ all mean the same thing, namely that
$$P(X=x \: | \: N=n) = {n \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}.$$
I prefer $X|(N=n) \sim Bin(n,p)$ simply because it is almost impossible to misinterpret. I would consider the expression $X\sim Bin(N,p)$ to be the least formal expression, but it is also the simplest, which may be why some authors prefer this notation.

I would never write $X|(N=n) \sim Bin(N,p)$, because if you are conditioning on $N=n$, then you should replace your $N$ with $n$.

Comment: Thank you ! I was very confused to me and now it is clear ! appreciate!